# Calendario Apex Oracle

Tags: apex

Hola estoy creando un calendario en apex y lo que queria conseguir es crear una accion dinamica ( estoy usando seleccionar fecha (calendario) y que cuando selecciono una de las celdas se me muestre en un elemento de texto la fecha y hora que selecciono, muy parecido a esto https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting-demo pero no consigo encontrar en que variable se encuentra el valor de la fecha que clicko, he probado con :APEX$NEW_START_DATE :APEX$OLD_START_DATE pero ninguna funciona, alguien sabe como solucionarlo? Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

no se si lo habrás visto pero arriba a la derecha tienes un botón que dice "Edit in CodePen". Si clickeas allí te llevará al código de ese calendario y tal vez podrías jugar en base a eso.

Perdón pero, por el momento, no puedo ayudarte más.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/406240)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).